# Dynamic express.js routes based on database entries with no restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, keystonejs

I've build an [KeystoneJS v5 app](https://www.keystonejs.com/) with a custom Express instance to serve data.
My data is stored in a Postgres database which contains the following model :

```
CREATE TABLE "Link" (
    id integer DEFAULT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer text,
    slug text
);
```

I have built dynamic routes based on slug attributes :

```js
knex('Link').select('slug').then(function(result){
  const data = result.map(x => x.slug)
  data.forEach(url => {
    express.get(`/${url}`, function (req, res) {
      res.render('index');
    })
  });
});
```

Everything works as expected but I have to restart my node server each time I insert new slug in the Link table.
Do you know how to avoid this ?
Thanks!

Comment: It should be the inverse, your express get should accept the slug as a param, then you can check if the slug exists within the table or else you can return a 404 or redirect to a different page. The reason why you have to restart is because the select is only ran at the time the server is booted up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the complete answer but here's something along the lines of what you're looking for.

1. Ensure we accept any slug on the route
2. I've used an async function to await the results from the DB
3. Render the index view (if the slug was found) or reply with a 404 if no entry was found within the table

Word of warning, I have not used keystoneJS or this knexjs package, so it might not be 100% correct, but should be a good example of what we're trying to achieve. I'm assuming knexjs rejects the promise if no results are found, but I'm not sure.

```
express.get(`/:slug`, async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const result = await knex('Link')
            .where({ slug: req.params.slug })
            .select('id');

        return res.render('index');
    } catch {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: "Not found" });
    }
});
```

If you're running an older version of Node.js, here's a version without async.

```
express.get(`/:slug`, function (req, res) {
    knex('Link')
        .where({ slug: req.params.slug })
        .select('id')
        .then((result) => {
            return res.render('index');
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return res.status(404).send({ message: "Not found" });
        });
});
```

Comment: Wow that's the advice I needed! Thanks!

I just have to adapt what you are saying due to knex because it always sends me a response even if there are no entries in the database.